# XSLT - Sum of node values using For each

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have the following XML

```
    <T1>
    <amount>100</amount>
    </T1>

    <T1>
    <amount>100</amount>
    <T1>
...
```

Now I'm supposed to sum all the amount node values to a single variable or element

I'm very new to this domain

kindly suggest the possible XSLT1.0 code please

i'm expecting the output as `<total>200</total>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [sum()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-sum) and catch all amount nodes

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(//amount[. != ''])"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:variable name="mySum" select="sum(//T1/amount)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <total>
        <xsl:value-of select="$mySum"/>
    </total>
    <!--    <anothMethod>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(//T1/amount)"/>
    </anothMethod> -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```